# Check if object on foreign key is set

Tags: python, django

There is this code:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    pass

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    some_model = models.ForeignKey(SomeModel)

om = OtherModel()
if om.some_model:
    pass
```

The exception thrown is:

```
models.DoesNotExist
```

Is there some nice way to check if object at foreign key is set instead of try...except or hasattr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a try...except is the best way to do this. This issue is mentioned in this (invalid) bug report: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12708

Answer (score 1):

```
om = OtherModel()
```

'Just' instantiates a python class. Use a model's manager to save the relationship before accessing the attribute, or set the field to null=True

```
om = OtherModel.objects.create()
```

Have a look at the [official manager documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/)